# Is there any way to use mbutil on Windows?

Tags: tilemill, mbtiles

I have used mbutil on Ubuntu. It's a very handy tool. I am curious if there is any way to use it on a Windows 64 bit machine. If there is a way please help me to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the answer by BradHards, yes it is a Python script so it will work in Windows. I was able to use it in Windows 7 after installing ActivePython.

(I first tried using IronPython but ran into problems with getting the required sqlite module to work)

1. Install ActivePython or another python that has sqlite.
2. Install mbutil (I just downloaded the zip archive and extracted to c:\)
3. From command line, run "setup.py install" to install mbutils
4. From command line, I copied mb-util > mb-util.py for convenience. So you can use "mb-util.py" instead of "python mb-util"
5. Run "mb-util.py -h", you should see the help information and now be able to use mbutil!

Comment: In step 4, did you copy mb-util.py to the root python path?

Answer (score 3):

Its a python script, so it should run anywhere. If you don't have python for Windows, you may like to download and install [ActiveState python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads).

Rather trying to use git on windows, the easiest way to get the python script is via a .zip download provided by github. The direct URL: https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/archive/master.zip

Unzip that, and you should be able to run it on a command line window.

Comment: I have installed the ActiveState python. I run the setup.py file of mbutil in Administrator:PyPM. Command line returns the following error.

Usage: setup.py [........]

error: no commands supplied

Comment: If you really want to install it (and you don't have to - should work fine without installation), then you have to provide an command (like "install"). This is documented on the main page (https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil/blob/master/README.md), and also in README.md in your checkout.

Comment: Probably I will never do it. I tried all the way and hang with it for 3 days to extract tiles. git on windows worked fine but hanged machine after extracting 3 million tiles. I am working in a big project where 23 million of tiles.

Comment: The stability of Windows and capabilities of mbtiles appears to be orthogonal to the original question about getting it running....

Answer (score 2):

You can try [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) software :

1.Copy the .mbtiles file to cygwin. Assuming that you installed "cygwin" at it's default directory the user home is mapped to c:\cygwin\home\

2.Run the following command: mb-util --scheme=osm Freguesias.mbtiles Freguesias

hope it will help you..

Nice explanation available on following [Pedros'blog](http://build-failed.blogspot.in/2012/03/custom-map-tiles-part-2-tilemill.html)

thanks..